# JPA CriteriaBuilder and Substring

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have a CriteriaBuilder where I am trying to get characters starting from 0 to 10. However I am not able to get the desired output.

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Emp> cq = cb.createQuery(Emp.class);
    Root<Emp> c = cq.from(Emp.class);
    cb.substring(c.<String>get("projDesc"), 0, 10);
    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(c.get("salary")));
    Query query = em.createQuery(cq);
    .....
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Don't you need to assign the cb.substring to something? Otherwise the effect will be lost, just like with `String.substring`

Comment: @geert3 is right, if you run a SQL query with Substring, you need to call the function and add to the select statement, the same with the `CriteriaBuilder`. `projDesc` is a `Emp.class`  property, but not the result of the substring, you need to add to the select statement of the `CriteriaBuilder`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#substring(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20int,%20int))

> Create an expression for substring extraction. Extracts a substring of
>   given length starting at the specified position. First position is 1.

Try doing `cb.substring(c.<String>get("projDesc"), 1, 10);`

---

I think you're forgetting to select the `Expression<E>`

Try `cq.select(cb.substring(c.<String>get("projDesc"), 1, 10))`
It will return `List<String>` if you need to Return the `Emp` you can use the

`cb.construct(Emp.class, e.get("prop1"), e.get("prop2"), cb.substring(c.<String>get("projDesc"), 1, 10)));`

Comment: Changing position from 0, to 1 didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Then I require clarification, what is the actual output and the expected output?

Comment: Actual - `Manage to finish project within stipulated time, however due to other hindrances project was prolonged for an year and incidents beyond jurisdiction.` Expected `Manage to`. Thanks

Comment: Edited according your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I also, faced same problem in which I have to substring first three char and fetch all accounts starting from 107 which is number. for that I have used **CriteriaBuilder** and **substring** method like below.

```
Predicate accountNumber = criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.substring(from.get("accountNumber").as(String.class), 0, 3), cwipAcc);
```

but unfortunately it is not working for **CriteriaBuilder** and **substring**. so I have used **like query** to resolve this issue by given code below.

```
Predicate accountNumber = criteriaBuilder.like(from.get("accountNumber").as(String.class), String.valueOf(cwipAcc) + "%");
```

here, I have just fetched all the records which is starting from 107 and so on.

Example:

```
public List<GLCharts> findAccountForCWIP(Long cwipAcc, Long glInfo) {
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap();
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<GLCharts> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(GLCharts.class);
        Root<GLCharts> from = criteriaQuery.from(GLCharts.class);

        Predicate accountNumber = criteriaBuilder.like(from.get("accountNumber").as(String.class), String.valueOf(cwipAcc) + "%");
        Predicate glCompanyInfo = criteriaBuilder.equal(from.join("gLCompanyInfo").get("id"), glInfo);

        Predicate finalPredicate = criteriaBuilder.and(accountNumber, glCompanyInfo);

        criteriaQuery.select(from).where(finalPredicate).orderBy(Stream.of(criteriaBuilder.asc(from.get("accountNumber"))).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        List<GLCharts> glChartsList = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();

        return glChartsList;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the problem because my requirement was to use a number into substr. Following is the sample code.

```
 @Override
    public List<SampleProfile> findNonSampleProfileBySequence(Long SampleNo) {
        List<SampleProfile> profiles = new ArrayList<>();
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<SampleProfile> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(SampleProfile.class);
        Root<SampleProfile> SampleProfileRoot = criteriaQuery.from(SampleProfile.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
        if (SampleUtil.isValidLong(SampleNo)) {
            String SampleStr = Long.toString(SampleNo);
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(SampleStr) && SampleStr.length() > 5) {
                String SampleSequence = SampleStr.substring(5);
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.substring(SampleProfileRoot.get(SampleProfile_.id).as(String.class), 6), SampleSequence));
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(SampleProfileRoot.get(SampleProfile_.address).get(Address_.department), SampleStr.substring(0,3)));
            }
        }
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(predicates)) {
            criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(Iterables.toArray(predicates, Predicate.class)));
            profiles = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setMaxResults(AbstractJpaDAO.MAX_ROW_LIMIT).getResultList();
        }
        return profiles;
    }
```

Also note that for performance benefits you have to create an index on the same. 
The Cast Keyword is important as Hibernate Dialect will create query like this, thus, it has to match with your index.

```
CREATE INDEX MY_SCHEMA_OWNER.IDX_SUBSTR_SMP_CODE ON MY_SCHEMA_OWNER.SMP_PROFILE (SUBSTR(**CAST**(SMP_CODE AS VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)),6));
```